# How to call block every n seconds with a Celluloid Actor?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, block, celluloid

I'm trying to create a Celluloid Actor that can accept a &block as a param and execute it every n seconds. However when I `call` the block from within the `every` loop, it never seems to do anything?

Take this example claass:

```
require 'celluloid/autostart'

class FooBar
  include Celluloid

  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block

    execute_block

    every(2) do
      puts "tick"
      execute_block
    end
  end

  def execute_block
    puts "tock"
    @block.call
  end

end
```

If I try the following:

```
a = FooBar.new { puts "Hi" }
```

Then I get this confusing output:

```
tock
Hi
tick
tock
tick
tock
tick
tock
tick
tock
tick
...
```

You can see that when I call `execute_block` the first time from outside the `every` block it works fine, and you can see that the `every` Timer is working correctly... But the block doesn't seem to every get called?

Anyone able to shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I noticed that if I moved the `puts "tock"` *beneath* the `@block.call` it would never get output at all...?